# Fortigate Open Ports

Tags: firewall, fortigate, fortinet

I need to open this port in Fortigate:

> 443   PSOM/TLS    Outbound    Data sharing sessions

But i dont know where I can open. I created a Custom Service, chose the option of TCP, but do not know if it's the right thing.

Does anyone know how can I open this port?

Thanks

Comment: Which FortiOS firmware version is your device running?

Comment: @DanielYusteAroca The version is v4.0,build0639,120906

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FortiGate doesn't care which protocol is running over the port 443, so you just need to create a policy and select the corresponding interfaces/addresses and as service you can select HTTPS. If it's a policy from internal network to WAN, be sure to select NAT also

Comment: To add to this, if you already have a policy in place for that source/destination, you can simply add the HTTPS service to the existing policy.